# Sequelize limit order issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Currently am having a problem with a simple query.

### Sequelize query:

```
db[TABLE_NAMES.BOOKING].findAll({
    order: [
      [ db[TABLE_NAMES.USER_BOOKING_RELATION], db[TABLE_NAMES.BOOKING_STATUS], sequelize.literal('status = \'Attention\''), 'desc'],
      ['created_at', 'desc']
    ],
    offset,
    limit: max,
    attributes: ['id', 'created_at'],
    where: { school_id: schoolId },
    include: [
      {
        attributes: ['id'],
        model: db[TABLE_NAMES.USER_BOOKING_RELATION],
        include: [
          {
            required: true,
            attributes: ['status'],
            model: db[TABLE_NAMES.BOOKING_STATUS],
            where: { status: { [Sequelize.Op.in]: ['Attention', 'Pending', 'Invited'] } }
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
```

### Models

```
const booking = sequelize.define(TABLE_NAMES.BOOKING, {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    deleted_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  });

const user_booking_relation = sequelize.define(TABLE_NAMES.USER_BOOKING_RELATION, {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true
  },
  user_id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false
  },
  booking_id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false
  },
  booking_status_id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
  },
  deleted_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE
  },
});

const booking_status = sequelize.define(TABLE_NAMES.BOOKING_STATUS, {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
    },
    deleted_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  });

booking.hasMany(user_booking_relation, { foreignKey: 'booking_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
user_booking_relation.belongsTo(booking, { foreignKey: 'booking_id', targetKey: 'id' });
booking_status.hasMany(user_booking_relation, { foreignKey: 'booking_status_id', sourceKey: 'id' });
user_booking_relation.belongsTo(booking_status, { foreignKey: 'booking_status_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

### Generated sql

```
SELECT `booking`.*,
       `user_booking_relations`.`id`                     AS `user_booking_relations.id`,
       `user_booking_relations->booking_status`.`id`     AS `user_booking_relations.booking_status.id`,
       `user_booking_relations->booking_status`.`status` AS `user_booking_relations.booking_status.status`
FROM (SELECT `booking`.`id`, `booking`.`created_at`
      FROM `booking` AS `booking`
      WHERE (`booking`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `booking`.`school_id` = 'a97b42e5-c864-4a4a-870b-737dd9700124')
        AND (SELECT `user_booking_relations`.`booking_id`
             FROM `user_booking_relation` AS `user_booking_relations`
                      INNER JOIN `booking_status` AS `booking_status`
                                 ON `user_booking_relations`.`booking_status_id` = `booking_status`.`id` AND
                                    (`booking_status`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
                                     `booking_status`.`status` IN ('Invited', 'Pending', 'Attention'))
             WHERE ((`user_booking_relations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) AND
                    `user_booking_relations`.`booking_id` = `booking`.`id`)
             LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY `booking`.`created_at` DESC
      LIMIT 0, 10) AS `booking`
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `user_booking_relation` AS `user_booking_relations` INNER JOIN `booking_status` AS `user_booking_relations->booking_status` ON
            `user_booking_relations`.`booking_status_id` = `user_booking_relations->booking_status`.`id` AND
            (`user_booking_relations->booking_status`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
             `user_booking_relations->booking_status`.`status` IN ('Invited', 'Pending', 'Attention')) )
                         ON `booking`.`id` = `user_booking_relations`.`booking_id` AND
                            (`user_booking_relations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `user_booking_relations->booking_status`.status = 'Attention' DESC, `booking`.`created_at` DESC;
```

### Result

```
// first page
// first page
[
  {
    "id": "4c74c307-3f7c-40c6-ba26-6d0e9f510bcc",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:15:07.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "7cb183c7-77cf-4fc8-9c98-eb2b8abf8d39",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1e8c9250-61b5-4610-b913-bd7aee866d5d",
    "created_at": "2020-06-01T14:48:00.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "0a9ba1a0-0929-4979-ba15-12c4903fd8a5",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Invited"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a1624f59-ebaa-4bc7-95b8-d0e96c1ec917",
    "created_at": "2020-06-01T08:45:12.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "fdbc677b-2035-44d2-8d9a-ab304e5624ee",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Pending"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

// second page
[
  {
    "id": "d18abf5c-c986-4c2c-a08d-02e1488745d8",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:14:10.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "585c0674-13cf-45ac-91bc-087b345a7b31",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "692ccef9-12b4-4aed-955b-11ce65512469",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:12:45.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "5c3d214d-833a-482d-aeb5-272af750f3bb",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1a5a56a9-4a6e-4548-a4d8-b388e6a9ac02",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:09:43.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "cea240f4-2529-44ae-a82d-f53d2dbbd0fc",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Expected result

```
// first page
[
  {
    "id": "4c74c307-3f7c-40c6-ba26-6d0e9f510bcc",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:15:07.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "7cb183c7-77cf-4fc8-9c98-eb2b8abf8d39",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "d18abf5c-c986-4c2c-a08d-02e1488745d8",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:14:10.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "585c0674-13cf-45ac-91bc-087b345a7b31",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "692ccef9-12b4-4aed-955b-11ce65512469",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:12:45.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "5c3d214d-833a-482d-aeb5-272af750f3bb",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

// second page
[
  {
    "id": "1a5a56a9-4a6e-4548-a4d8-b388e6a9ac02",
    "created_at": "2020-05-30T20:09:43.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "cea240f4-2529-44ae-a82d-f53d2dbbd0fc",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Attention"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1e8c9250-61b5-4610-b913-bd7aee866d5d",
    "created_at": "2020-06-01T14:48:00.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "0a9ba1a0-0929-4979-ba15-12c4903fd8a5",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Invited"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a1624f59-ebaa-4bc7-95b8-d0e96c1ec917",
    "created_at": "2020-06-01T08:45:12.000Z",
    "user_booking_relations": [
      {
        "id": "fdbc677b-2035-44d2-8d9a-ab304e5624ee",
        "booking_status": {
          "status": "Pending"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As we can see from the generated SQL, bookings with any of those statuses are initially selected and then sorted. I need Attention bookings to go first. How can I get around this or fix it? Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Show model definitions and associations. Did you try `subQuery: false`?

Comment: I tried to use `subQuery: false` but it leads to another issue. Wrong booking count is returned if the booking has more than one user_booking_relation.

Comment: In that case try to indicate `separate: true` for the `user_booking_relation` include